# Locking Dictionary-Entry vs ConcurrentDictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm trying to get the following work: I get a markdown text and need to alter each of the rules, f.e. # --> h1, * * means italic etc.

It's a contest and the performance is one of the main points.

So my approach is quite simple: I split the lines, then create dictionaries for each rule and start a task for each for them, so they can be worked on parallel:

```
    private Dictionary<Rule, Dictionary<int, string>> SplitLinesByRule()
    {
        var result = new Dictionary<Rule, Dictionary<int, string>>();
        Dictionary<int, string> tmpLines;

        tmpLines = _formattedLines.Where(f => string.IsNullOrEmpty(f.Value)).ToDictionary(f => f.Key, f => f.Value);
        result.Add(Rule.Block, tmpLines);

        tmpLines = _formattedLines.Where(f => f.Value.StartsWith("*")).ToDictionary(f => f.Key, f => f.Value);
        result.Add(Rule.Enumeration, tmpLines);

        tmpLines = _formattedLines.Where(f => f.Value.Count(ff => ff == '*') > 1).ToDictionary(f => f.Key, f => f.Value);
        result.Add(Rule.Cursive, tmpLines);

        tmpLines = _formattedLines.Where(f => f.Value.StartsExactlyWith("~~~~")).ToDictionary(f => f.Key, f => f.Value);
        result.Add(Rule.Code, tmpLines);

        tmpLines = _formattedLines.Where(f => f.Value.StartsExactlyWith("####")).ToDictionary(f => f.Key, f => f.Value);
        result.Add(Rule.Headline4, tmpLines);

        tmpLines = _formattedLines.Where(f => f.Value.Length >= 3 && f.Value.StartsExactlyWith("###")).ToDictionary(f => f.Key, f => f.Value);
        result.Add(Rule.Headline3, tmpLines);

        tmpLines = _formattedLines.Where(f => f.Value.Length >= 2 && f.Value.StartsExactlyWith("##")).ToDictionary(f => f.Key, f => f.Value);
        result.Add(Rule.Headline2, tmpLines);

        tmpLines = _formattedLines.Where(f => f.Value.Length >= 1 && f.Value.StartsExactlyWith("#")).ToDictionary(f => f.Key, f => f.Value);
        result.Add(Rule.Headline1, tmpLines);

        tmpLines = _formattedLines.Except(result.SelectMany(f => f.Value)).ToDictionary(f => f.Key, f => f.Value);
        result.Add(Rule.None, tmpLines);

        return result;
    }
```

Followed by:

```
        Task[] tasks = new Task[]
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                HandleBlocks(lineChunks.First(f => f.Key == Rule.Block).Value);
            }),

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                HandleCode(lineChunks.First(f => f.Key == Rule.Code).Value);
            }),

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                HandleCursive(lineChunks.First(f => f.Key == Rule.Cursive).Value);
            }),

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                HandleEnumeration(lineChunks.First(f => f.Key == Rule.Enumeration).Value);
            }),

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                HandleH1(lineChunks.First(f => f.Key == Rule.Headline1).Value);
            }),

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                HandleH2(lineChunks.First(f => f.Key == Rule.Headline2).Value);
            }),

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                HandleH3(lineChunks.First(f => f.Key == Rule.Headline3).Value);
            }),

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                HandleH4(lineChunks.First(f => f.Key == Rule.Headline4).Value);
            }),

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                HandleNoneRule(lineChunks.First(f => f.Key == Rule.None).Value);
            })
        };

        Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

My problem is: A line can have more than one rule, so my first approach was a ConcurrentDictionary and add Lines, which couldn't be updated to a posion queue and handle them seperately:

```
    private void TryUpdate(KeyValuePair<int, string> line, string newValue)
    {
        bool ok = _formattedLines.TryUpdate(line.Key, newValue, line.Value);
        if (!ok) _poisonQueue.Add(line.Key, line.Value);
    }
```

I guess this would work, but the performance wouldn't be that great and it's getting really complicated to check every Line, which didn't work, again for the rules.

Another approach would be to create a normal Dictionary and basically lock the row it is updated, so there might be more than one row being updated, but only the same row once (not working example):

```
    private void TryUpdate(KeyValuePair<int, string> line, string newValue)
    {
        lock (line.Key as object)
        { 
            _formattedLines[line.Key] = newValue;
        }
    }
```

The problem is of course, only the last rule would be updated, so I'd need to to something else here.

Is there another approach I didn't take care of? Would there be another approach be more performant than trying to handle each rule for itself?

Comment: Every LINQ query has to parse the whole file, so you check each line `number_of_rules` times, whereas you could eliminate a number of checks most of the time. This is somewhat inefficient. I think you should parallelize over portions of the file, not on rules.

Comment: Moreover, if you have an entry that has, say, lots of h1 transformations to do and practically nothing else, you'll have a Task doing all the work while the others will finish in no time.

Comment: `lock (line.Key as object)` is not going to work properly. It is going to cause boxing of the integer every time resulting in a new lock object on each method activation. You need an instance of a reference type to use with `lock`. There's a reason the compiler gives you an error when you try to lock a value type expression. You could define a new reference type that simply serves as a key that contains an int field.

Comment: It's a contest? What's the award? Are you going to share?

Comment: No Peter, its just a explenation of my motivation, it's a really small contest and I'm doing such stuff for learning purposes.
@PatriceGahide: What would be the other approach? Since some rules apply to more than one line, f.E. Lists, its not possible to split the lanes just at, lets say, 50 pieces and work on them.
mikez: It was just an idea, and I'm basically not sure what the concurrentdictionry is doing for me except saying "no"

Comment: In addition to lists, what rule has to be processed as a whole group? Anyway, you just have to make sure you don't split on a problematic line (you go forward or backward one line at a time until you reach a safe line, that is just a matter of a few jumps).

Comment: Why don't you make it work first without multi threading, then make it fast, and only then try multi threading if you still need more performance.

Comment: @Maarten If I'd make it this way, all I'd have to do is removing the Tasks-Start and thats it. Patrice, probably I check at the splitting, if the Line is in anhother rule already and handle the synchronious after all Tasks are finished. Thanks for the input so far.